# sql select display row data as columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a sql select query that extracts result as:

```
login_count  login_type
2000         iPhone
7000         browser
```

But i want the result as:

```
iphone_login  browser_login
2000          7000
```

i.e. i want to extract row1-col1 as col1 and row2-col2 as col2 using a select query.

My original query is

```
select count(login_count), login_type from log_table group by login_type;
```

Thanks,
Gaurav

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    SUM( IF(login_type = 'iPhone', 1, 0) ) AS iphone_login,
    SUM( IF(login_type = 'browser', 1, 0) ) AS browser_login
FROM log_table
```

Comment: Incidentally, how many times have you given this answer? That isn't meant as a criticism, it just seems like I see at least one new "select rows as columns" question *every single day*. We need some kind of community-wide close-as-duplicate binge... If we could agree on which of these questions has the best 'canonical' answers... :)

Comment: @Eray Then use the original query and let Excel transpose the types into columns for you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option that works in MySQL **and** in other dbms as well.

```
select sum(case when login_type = 'iPhone'  then 1 else 0 end) as iphone_login
      ,sum(case when login_type = 'browser' then 1 else 0 end) as browser_login
from log_table
```